# In Firebase database, how to keep data consistency when both push and update operations are needed?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have the following database in `Firebase`, when a user send a new message to another user, it need to push a new message to `"ChatThreads/hash(User1,User2)"` and update both `"UserChats/User1/User2"` and `"UserChats/User2/User1"`.

```
"ChatThreads" : {
  "hash(User1,User2)" : {
    "1" : {
      "message" : "Hello",
      "sender" : "User2",
      "time" : 9835592
    },
    "2" : {
      "message" : "hi",
      "sender" : "User1",
      "time" : 10000000
    },
    "3" : {
      "message" : "I am boss",
      "sender" : "User2",
      "time" : 14835592
    }
    }
  }
},    
"UserChats" : {
  "User1" : {
    "User2" : {
      "lastTime" : 14835592,
      "latestMessage" : "I am boss"
    }
  },
  "User2" : {
    "User1" : {
      "lastTime" : 14835592,
      "latestMessage" : "I am boss"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I keep data consistency in the case? 
In the document of `Firebase`, the method of creating a reference to multiple update's common parent and put all updates in a map was introduced. However, in this case, not only update but also push is needed.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `push()` without any arguments, you get a unique key that's always generated on the client.  (Push ids are always generated locally.) With that key, you can then construct the path to the location where you want to add the data you along with all the other data for that update.

Comment: This is quite tricky. How to do a rolling back if any step fails?